# UINavagitionBar appearance proxy doesn't respond to setTitleTextAttributes?

Tags: ios5, uinavigationbar

I'm trying to customize the shadow offset of the title of my UINavigationBar, the documentation [states](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationBar_Class/Reference/UINavigationBar.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UINavigationBar/titleTextAttributes) that you can do this by calling setTitleTextAttributes with a dictionary specifying the attributes and values.

This works great for my back button and bar buttons, but not the UINavigationBar. My app's crashing with unrecognized selector sent to instance.

Here's my simple code that I call from within `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`:

```
id navigationbar = [UINavigationBar appearance];
[navigationbar setTitleTextAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSValue valueWithUIOffset:UIOffsetMake(0, 1)] forKey:UITextAttributeTextShadowOffset] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

My exception breakpoint hits with this in output log:

```
...-[_UIAppearance setTitleTextAttributes:forState:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1176cb0
```

Answer (score 2):

Yep, my bad, as always! :(

I was sending it with the forState incantation which only works with buttons, etc. UINavigationbar doesn't have state.

Sending it without the forState parameter works fine.